# PHP Get first 3 words from string

Tags: php

The following code splits a string and selects all of the alphanumeric words containing minimum 3 letters. However instead of getting all the words from the string, I want to get only first 3 valid words, but the problem is with the loop. How can I stop the loop as soon as 3 valid words are found from the string.

PS. If there is an alternative approach to the same thing, please suggest.
Thanks.

```
$string = "test test TEST test- -test _test blsdk.bldf,las";

$arr = preg_split('/[,\ \.;]/', $string);
$keywords = array_unique($arr);
foreach ($keywords as $keyword){
            if ((preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]/", $keyword) ) && (strlen($keyword) > 3)){
                    echo $keyword;
                    echo "<br />";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a variable which counts up when a matching keyword is found. when counter reaches maximum then break the `foreach` loop

```
$string = "test test TEST test- -test _test blsdk.bldf,las";

$arr = preg_split('/[,\ \.;]/', $string);
$keywords = array_unique($arr);
$i=0;
foreach ($keywords as $keyword){
            if ((preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]/", $keyword) ) && (strlen($keyword) > 3)){
                    echo $keyword;
                    echo "<br />";
                    $i++;
                    if ($i==3) break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use this if condition instead to make it more simple as well. e.g.: if ($i < 3)

Comment: @SaeedAfzal That does not make much sense as including `$i<3` in `if`-condition does not break `foreach` loop which has to process total array then.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the 'break' keyword, try this (code not tested) -

```
$string = "test test TEST test- -test _test blsdk.bldf,las";

$arr = preg_split('/[,\ \.;]/', $string);
$keywords = array_unique($arr);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($keywords as $keyword){
            if ((preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]/", $keyword) ) && (strlen($keyword) > 3)){
                    echo $keyword;
                    echo "<br />";
                    $counter = $counter + 1;
                    if ($counter == 3) break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cut off the rest.

```
array_splice($arr, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a different approach As you use a regex to check your results maybe it is
more clear, and maybe efficients, to use [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to do your work for you.

```
<?php
$string = "test le  test TEST test- -test _test blsdk.bldf,las";

$arr=array();
preg_match_all('/\b([0-9A-Za-z]{3,})\b/', $string, $arr);
$keywords = array_slice(array_unique($arr[0]),0,3);
echo join('<br/>', $keywords);
```

In the question you state you want to select words with a minimum length of 3,
but you test their length with `> 3`. Change the regular expression accordingly if needed.

Note: made the words unique as in the original test.

Comment: Thanks, this is wonderful, however I have a few questions. First, your example gives a warning at last line `Notice: Array to string conversion`. Second, as you see my code, I use array_unique to get unique words. Could you please modify an example and tell how i can get the first 3 words from the above string with minimum length 3 containing only 0-9a-Z.

Comment: The notice is due to the online scripting without testing it, `preg_match_all` returns a multidimensional array and you have your keywords into the $arr[0] array, not the $arr one.  Once you have the array you have an array similar to yours but with the words that are too short filtered out. You can just take the first three

Comment: [a-Z]  does not do what one might expect, i.e. [a-zA-Z]

Comment: thanks a lot. Consider a word in the string abcd_efgh, this will accept it as 2 different words abcd and efgh, which is undesired. since i want only 0-9a-z. Is there a wayd to ignore such words?

Comment: @Roman: use word boundaries (replaced the regexp in the example)